# background: linear-gradient() not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I made a simple page on codepen but `background: linear-gradient` is not working on mobile.  It is showing color on the computer but not in mobile.

Here is my code link: https://codepen.io/jjarus/pen/OGwJqv

And my CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(orange, white, green);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

put this also in your css

```
background: linear-gradient(orange,white,green);
```

your css is specific for chrome browser as you mentioned webkit.

Comment: it's working in firefox but not in chrome on mobile

Answer (score 1):

In your css, you just set gradient background only for webkit browsers:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(orange,white,green);
```

Simply, add the following code to your css:

```
background: linear-gradient(orange,white,green);
```

I suggest you use [`cssgradient.io`](https://cssgradient.io/) for creating css gradient background easily with the highest compatibility with any browser.

Comment: it's still not working. you can see on your smartphone

Comment: it's working in firefox but not in chrome on mobile